# legend after for loop in matlab doesn't work

Tags: matlab, legend

I want to add legend for this m file but it doesn't work correctly

```
Inp=[1 2 .1 2 .2 3 .1 1.5 .5 1.6 2 2.5 3 3 3.5 3.5;
 .1 .2 .3 .3 .4 .4 .5 .5 .6 .7 .6 .7 .6 .75 .8 .55];
 Out=[1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1];
% 1=Bomber
% 2=Fighter
figure(1); hold on
for itt=1:length(Inp)
if Out(1,itt)==1
    plot(Inp(1,itt),Inp(2,itt),'ro','MarkerFace','r','MarkerSize',10);
elseif Out(2,itt)==1
    plot(Inp(1,itt),Inp(2,itt),'k^','MarkerFace','g','MarkerSize',10);
elseif Out(3,itt)==1
    plot(Inp(1,itt),Inp(2,itt),'bs','MarkerFace','c','MarkerSize',10);
  end
end

xlim([0 4])
ylim([0 1])
h=legend('Fighter','Bomber','Other');
```

please help me

Comment: @rayryeng: I think you missed the problem -- He doesn't want a legend entry for each iteration of the loop, but for the three distinct kinds of unique object.  (He should lose the loop altogether and use boolean masking to get all objects of kind #1, #2, #3, so that all objects of the same kind exist in a single series)

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah you're right.  I misread that part of the code.  I'll reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Legends (and just about everything) work better (and faster) if you plot all points corresponding to a single legend as a single series.  Vectorize!

In your example, it would look like this (this replaces the loop):

```
mask = (Out(1,:)==1);   % mask vector getting all kind #1
plot(Inp(1,mask),Inp(2,mask),'ro','MarkerFace','r','MarkerSize',10);

mask = (Out(2,:)==1);   %  get kind #2
plot(Inp(1,mask),Inp(2,mask),'k^','MarkerFace','g','MarkerSize',10);

mask = (Out(3,:)==1);   % get kind #3
plot(Inp(1,mask),Inp(2,mask),'bs','MarkerFace','c','MarkerSize',10);
```

Now, the legend will simply start working, with the command you already have.

```
h=legend('Fighter','Bomber','Other');
```

Comment: I replace your code instead of my for loop but it doesn't show the bomber and other

Comment: Oh right, I messed up the second and third conditions.  Fixing.

Comment: Is there anyway to add legend after for loop?? I want to use this code in neural network and pattern recognition and when I insert your code the network didn't work correctly.

Comment: @alieskandari: You already did.  The problem is that your for loop produced 16 separate datasets, instead of 3.  So you will need 16 legend entries, and the order is data-dependent, because you for loop plotted things in data-dependent order.  It's much much better to do vectorized plotting like I showed, so you have three datasets, and therefore 3 legend entries, in the same order.

Comment: @alieskandari: How would my code break pattern recognition?  Is the pattern recognition working on the graph instead of the `In` and `Out` vectors.

Comment: I use this code after training network
`figure(1)
for jtt=1:5
PlaneMass =input('new plane''s Mass ?', 's')
Mass=str2num(PlaneMass);
PlaneSpeed=input('new plane''s Speed ?', 's')
Speed=str2num(PlaneSpeed);

A=sim(net,[Mass Speed]');

if A(1) > .5
    plot(Mass,Speed,'bo','MarkerFace',[.3 .3 .3],'MarkerSize',10);
elseif A(2)>.5
    plot(Mass,Speed,'g^','MarkerFace',[.5 .5 .5],'MarkerSize',10);
elseif A(3)>.5
    plot(Mass,Speed,'bs','MarkerFace',[.5 .5 .5],'MarkerSize',10);
end

end`

Comment: And when I input new data it doesn't show in figure(1)